# Html5 localstorage between two pages

Tags: html, local-storage

Am trying to make a game using Html5. my need is i have menu html page with 3 buttons one,two,three. when am clicking on that button am storing that value like one or two or three storing in a variable and it'll go to next page game.html. and i can retrieve it too.

```
localStorage.setItem("value",$(this).val()); //storing 1,2 or 3 in value
 var value_menu = localStorage.getItem("value"); //getting value in value_menu
```

here i have a back button in game.html page, if i click on that it'll go to menu page and am removing the key values from localstorage.

```
localStorage.removeItem("value"); (or) localStorage.clear();
```

if am again click on the buttons in menu page, the value showing as null. why its showing as null ? because if i click on button the localstorage have to store value again. isn't it?

otherwise am making any mistakes? need some explanations.

thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because null is the default value when something does not exist and you delete the value when yo go back so it is "logic" .... the value is null because it does not exist because you remove it.
Okay? ;-)

You can interpret null as 'not selected' (in your case it IS not selected and that's true because you have deleted it when the user go back). The next thing you have to do is to check if the value is null (value === null) and to do nothing when it is null (not showing it). Or much better: if( typeof value == "number" && value > 0 ) etc.

It think it is better to not remove the choice of the user until the user left the first/entry page.

Pure interest: What kind of game do you want to create?